# java error, jnetpcap library in eclipse

Tags: java, jnetpcap

I try to write simple sniffer, i would like to get list of devices. here is my function but doesn't work, i don't know what is wrong because i just started work with this library.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.io.*;

import org.jnetpcap.*;

public class sniffer
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List<PcapIf> alldevs = new ArrayList<PcapIf>();
        StringBuilder errorbuf = new StringBuilder();

        //pobieranie listy urzadzen

        int r = Pcap.findAllDevs(alldevs, errorbuf);
        if (r == Pcap.NOT_OK || alldevs.isEmpty())
        {
            System.err.println("Can't read list of devices, error is: " +errorbuf.toString());
            return;
        }

    }
}
```

i don't understand what do with this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.slytechs.library.NativeLibrary.dlopen(Ljava/lang/String;)J
        at com.slytechs.library.NativeLibrary.dlopen(Native Method)
        at com.slytechs.library.NativeLibrary.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.slytechs.library.JNILibrary.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.slytechs.library.JNILibrary.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at com.slytechs.library.JNILibrary.register(Unknown Source)
        at com.slytechs.library.JNILibrary.register(Unknown Source)
        at com.slytechs.library.JNILibrary.register(Unknown Source)
        at org.jnetpcap.Pcap.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        at sniffer.sniffer.main(sniffer.java:18)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above exception will be

Thrown if the Java Virtual Machine cannot find an appropriate native-language definition of a method declared native.

try to check the path of JDK set properly pointing to correct library of java in buildpath.

and make sure correct jdk version is installed. no mess up with x86/x64 installs.`

Comment: I have win7 x32, and add jnetcap.jar to buildpath.

Comment: jnetcap 1.3.0 and java 6 with 64bit ?

Comment: so jdk is also 32 bit you downloaded and jnetcap version also compatible one ?

Comment: oh, by accident i download jnetpcap for 64-bit -.-  ,thanks for help :) i don't know that 1.4.0 is for 64, not 32.

Comment: I am using JDK 1.8 and jnetpcap 1.4 in 64 bit linux pc(Works in windows). But nothing is working. can anyone give a download link from where their solution worked.

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse, under *Configurations* (*Debug* or *Run*), *Arguments* tab, in *VM Arguments* use the following:

```
-Djava.library.path=<path to jnetpcap.dll or libjnetpcap.so>
```

Comment: I added the path of libjnetpcap.so to VM Arguments like this but still getting the same error.